# Hierarchical/Multilayer/Nested Instrumental Variable Regression

Tags: regression, inference, causality, instrumental-variables

If we can view classical instrumental variable regression as "two-layer" (from instrumental variable to covariate and then to the response), is there any "hierarchical/multilayer/nested" version of instrumental variable regression? (Any keyword to search for would help.)